# Java - JVM Garbage Collectors in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat.
In terms of the Java Garbage Collection I guess that the option B of the service is better than the option A, since the object does not remain in the memory, right ?

**option A:**

```
@Override
    public List<HotelPriceSummary> overRanked7d(User user) {

        List<HotelPriceSummary> overRanked7dList =

                allNonFavoritedHotels(user)
                        .parallelStream()
                        .filter(HotelPriceSummary.overRanked7dHotelsPredicate())                            
                        .sorted(comparing((HotelPriceSummary cps) -> cps.getDailyPercentageChange()).reversed())
                        .collect(toList());

        return overRanked7dList;
    }
```

**option B:**

```
@Override
    public List<HotelPriceSummary> overRanked7d(User user) {

        return

                allNonFavoritedHotels(user)
                        .parallelStream()
                        .filter(HotelPriceSummary.overRanked7dHotelsPredicate())                            
                        .sorted(comparing((HotelPriceSummary cps) -> cps.getDailyPercentageChange()).reversed())
                        .collect(toList());


    }
```

Comment: at least from code smell aspect. Option B is much better. Even a must. From GC aspect, there is no difference, I think. All depends on that List how used.

Comment: I would like to point out that the threadpool used by `parallelStream()` has [as many threads as the machine has processors by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). As e.g. Tomcat may have more than well above 100 requests threads you could actually bottleneck your application by using parallelstream. I have also read that `parallelStream()` behaves differently in a servlet context but can't find the source right now

Comment: And to answer your question: it doesn't matter if you assign the result of your stream operations into a local variable or not (at least from a GC perspective) as the list is stored on the heap and only a reference to said list is returned from the given function, not a copy of some sort.

Comment: The object will remain in memory as long as the caller of `overRanked7d` uses it. Unless the code optimizer can prove that this usage doesn’t need the memory. Then, the object might get reclaimed even while it is used. The general purpose of the garbage collector is to stop you from thinking what it does, so you can focus on the actual programming task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From JVM implementation point of view, the only difference is declaring a new object reference to the returned object. Hence, no new object is being created in either case and no new memory is being used. 
From coding perspective, option B is preferred.